# How to set up game over at the end of the game with the same condition as the beginning?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, nstimer

I'm not sure if I worded the question right but basically I'm working on a game that has a start button, that triggers a 10 second timer when the user clicks it, then the user has 10 seconds to collect a bunch of cats. Everything works good, my problem is that the code is set up like this in the `update`: method:

```
    //reset counter if starting:
if (startGamePlay) {
    startTime = currentTime;
    startGamePlay = NO;
}

countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime - startTime);
if (countDownInt>0) {
    countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TIME REMAINING: %i", countDownInt];
}else if (countDownInt <= 0) {
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
          [SKAction runBlock:^{
        countDown.text = @"";
    }],
          [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
          [SKAction runBlock:^{
       //transition
    }],
    ]]];
}
```

Where I want to insert a transition to the game over scene where it says //transition. The problem is that this is the same code that is at the beginning of the game because time timer is only initialised when the user clicks a button, at which point the startGamePlay BOOL is set to YES, and the timer is activated.

How can I insert this:

```
gameOverScene *gameOver = [[gameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:gameOver transition:[SKTransition moveInWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionUp duration:0.5]];
```

**What changes would I have to make to make it work? Another bool possibly? Where would I put the bool?**

This is the tap method if needed:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"tapCircle"]) {
            score = score + 1;
        }
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"startButton"] && _startButton.zPosition == 10.0) {
            startGamePlay = YES;
            _startButton.zPosition = -2.0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question of yours is very hard to understand so I am not sure I got it quite right...

The 1st snippet you posted seems to be some method invoked by some timer and is being called constantly no matter the game state? If so, it is not the best design but still: You do not need another boolean value, you should rather use an integer to represent the game state or rather yet create an enumeration:

```
typedef enum:NSInteger {
    gameStateBegin,
    gameStatePlaying,
    gameStateOver,
    gameStateWiting
}gameState;

- (void)onTimer {
    switch (self.state) {
        case gameStateBegin: {
            startTime = currentTime;
            self.state = gameStatePlaying;
            break;
        }
        case gameStatePlaying: {
            countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime - startTime);
            if (countDownInt>0) {
                countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TIME REMAINING: %i", countDownInt];
            }
            else if (countDownInt <= 0) {
                self.state = gameStateOver;
            }
            break;
        }
        case gameStateOver: {
            self.state = gameStateWiting;
            [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
                countDown.text = @"";
            }],
                                                 [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
                //transition

            }],
                                                 ]]];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to I create a property for state, it's asking me for one @matic oblak

Comment: @property gameState state;

Comment: Kk errors are fixed, but now I don't know where to call the method? InitWithSize? when user taps?